# Simulated 3D hit point from surface normal

Tags: normal-mapping

Here is an illustration describing what I'm trying to do...

[image: Here is an illustration describing what I'm trying to do...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into [parallax mapping](http://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-Lighting/Parallax-Mapping). This technique takes given geometry and  a normal map to redefine the position that a given texel is displayed at. It does that by calculating an offset from the pixel's position using the normal map, just as you are trying to do. 
I did not yet implement parallax mapping in my engine yet, so I cannot give you a fitting solution, but maybe parallax mapping's math will give you an idea of what to do.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply! the parallax way works :)